# testing scanf != EOF in a while loop failure

Tags: c, scanf, eof

so i have started a C class and although i have an experience in C# and C++ i have reached a point where i am stuck very early on regarding scanf = EOF

```
    printf("Students, please enter heights!\n");
double maleAvg = 0, femaleAvg = 0;
int currentHeight = 0, malecount = 0, femalecount = 0;
while(scanf("%d",&currentHeight) != EOF)
{
    if(currentHeight > 0)
    {
        femaleAvg += currentHeight;
        femalecount++;
    }
    else if (currentHeight < 0)
    {
        maleAvg += currentHeight;
        malecount++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error! Invalid height 0!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
if(femalecount == 0)
{
    printf("No girls in class! :(\n");
}
else
{
    femaleAvg /= femalecount;
    printf("Average girls height is: %f\n",femaleAvg);
}
if(malecount == 0)
{
    printf("No boys in class! :(\n");
}
else
{
    maleAvg /= malecount;
    printf("Average boy height is: %f\n",maleAvg);
}
return 0;
```

from what i understand this is the correct way to create this loop so it reads until the end of the file. however, i found that while it does enter the loop based off the amount of numbers written, it doesn't do anything after the while loop and just gets stuck. i tried and printing a message immediately after the end of the loop but nothing was printed.

Comment: Can you add more code? I would write `while(scanf("%d",&currentHeight) == 1)`, loop as long as `scanf` could read 1 integer.

Comment: What is your input? If you have input that can't be converted to a decimal number, `scanf` returns 0 and tracks back to before the unparsed input, effectively creating an infinite loop. Use mch's suggestion or scan a word with `%s`, then parse it with `strtol`.

Comment: Read the manual. This function returns the number of input items assigned, and *[if] an error or end-of-file occurs after conversion has begun, the number of conversions which were successfully completed is returned.* Try this instead: `while(scanf("%d",&currentHeight) == 1)`

Comment: Please the full [mcve] including input, output, what it needs to do and the code *inside the loop*, variable declarations and so on - at least.

Comment: i tried doing == 1 but that gave the same issue i mentioned

Comment: You mention that you want to read from a file, but `scanf` reads from the "standard input channel", `stdin`, which usually is input typed interactively into the console. If you don't type anything, the program just waits for you to type something. You can redirect your input like this: `myprog < myfile` or you could use `fscanf`, which takes an additional parameter, the open file, as first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from `stdin` never closes and won't ever return EOF under "normal" input. You can force and EOF by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (on Linux) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (on Windows/DOS):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    int s = 0;
    printf("Enter integer, Ctrl+D to compute the sum:\n");
    while (scanf("%d", &i) != EOF) {
        s += i;
    }
    printf("Sum = %d\n", s);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
Enter integer, Ctrl+D to compute the sum:
1
5
4
3
Sum = 13
```

But you should really check the return value and do the processing accordingly, as it will fail if you input e.g. `1.2` (and in general: *always check return values*).

Note that, as @Toby Speight indicated, you can also redirect from a file with your favourite shell that will send the EOF:

```
./a.out < numbers.txt
```

with `numbers.txt` being like:

```
1
5
4
3
```

Comment: IIRC, on CP/M and related systems (e.g. DOS), C-z is used instead of C-d.  And `stdin` is easily closed without keystrokes - just connect it to a pipe or a file, for example.

Comment: @TobySpeight of course `Ctrl+Z`! I added information on file redirection too, thanks.